# Why does viewing facebook with firefox 3.6 on Windows 7 change my keyboard from US to UK?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, keyboard-layout, firefox-3.6, regional-settings

I have a US keyboard. I am using a copy of Windows 7 bought in the UK. My default keyboard is US. All applications default to US keyboard, even Firefox.

And yet when I load Facebook for the first time on Firefox 3.6 my keyboard automatically changes to UK. No, I don't want a UK keyboard.

Firstly: why does this happen?

Secondly: how can I make my firefox respect my default keyboard?

Note, I can manually go click on the keyboard icon in the system tray and change it back to US but there is absolutely zero valid reason for the application to change the keyboard in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing UK keyboard from the "regional settings" and make Us the only and default keyboard option. That should solve the issue.

As for the reason, why it happens, is because, facebook changes locale settings every time it loads. So, every time, you load facebook, it sees that your locale setting is UK, which I guess, you have not yet changed in "Regional Settings", and change the keyboard automatically.

Comment: but my locale IS the UK. Yet my keyboard is USA. Wait.. you're telling me that.. oh God.. geographically challenged human beings making assumptions that people never travel again.

Comment: Facebook assumes that your system locale is the one which you are in, so, it makes sense to change the keyboard in that case. If you are in US, why do you need UK to be set as locale for your system? I am in India, and the first thing I do during installation is to make sure, the regional settings are for India. That is after all the point of having the option to change regional settings, isn't it.
Anyways, can you let others know, if changing the locale to US, and removing UK keyboard, helps you or not, so that others can help you out, if it doesn't work.

Comment: If I *WANT* my keyboard to change then *I* will change it. An application should *NOT* change my keyboard.